# Formating json for fullcalendar

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I have an external JSON that I want as the source of events. It looks like this:

```
{
"cabin1": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Cabin on the hill",
    "bookings": [
        {
            "begin_dt": "2020-12-06 17:00:00",
            "end_dt": "2020-12-11 13:00:00"
        },
        {
            "begin_dt": "2020-12-26 17:00:00",
            "end_dt": "2020-12-29 13:00:00"
        },
```

I have figured out how to transform the begin_dt/end_dt to start/end but what about "bookings", should that be transformed into events?

Comment: Right down the bottom of https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed there's an example of the basic JSON structure (in the "Dates" section actually). It needs to be just an array, not wrapped in any other object structure

Comment: If, for any reason, you can't change your JSON source to match the right structure or field names, you'll need to use this pattern to make the Ajax call manually and transform the data before giving it to fullCalendar: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function